# Jquery Hover over gallery image effect

Tags: jquery, hover, border, effect

I'm new to jquery. I found a lightbox gallery on a website that I want to emulate. I know how to use the standard light box code here http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

But I want my thumbnails to have a hover effect where a new color border appears with text over the image like on the site below.

Shown here http://wozcreative.com/

This is a wordpress site with a plugin.

How do I do the same with jquery?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your answer is in the code of the page in question

```
<!-- Portfolio Effect Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#portfolio li', this ).mouseenter(function() {
                jQuery('.description', this).slideDown('fast');
         });
         jQuery('#portfolio li', this ).mouseleave(function() {
                 jQuery('.description', this).slideUp('fast');
             });
         });
    </script>
```

I'm not sure why he's calling JQuery explicitly (I think it's because he's also using yui) but you could replace the `JQuery` with `$`

Anyway, it looks like he has list elements with images and hidden descriptions, when you mouse over it unhides the description.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. There is some sort of syntax error on line 6... How do I fix this? http://aemcreative.com/test/test

Comment: Well, for starters it looks like you accidently copied the script tags from the example into your .js file. You only need the <script> tags if your inlining JS in your HTML.

Comment: Not a problem, just remember to mark your question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you are looking for.

[WP Visual Slidebox Builder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-visual-slidebox-builder/)

Comment: User asking the question refer to a WordPress plugin. He wants to do the same using jQuery, not another WP plugin.